# To what extent are the astronomically observed black hole candidates compatible with GR black holes?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, observational-astronomy

Do they all fit Schwarzschild black holes? How people compare them with more complicate BH solutions as spinning BH solutions (even if they are not known analytically), say.

I'd like more than qualitative comments, if possible.

Comment: Schwarzschild black holes are eternal black holes (BH that have existed for all time. No physical black hole satisfies this property. In fact, almost all astronomical black holes spin and hence are closer to Kerr black holes.

Comment: @Prahar I thought that people called "astrophysical BH" the ones with an accompanying scenario devising a physical process leading to its formation. Not really the case of a Kerr BH, if I'm right. Despite the question of whether a Schwarzschild BH is eternal or not, my question persists.

Comment: @user34134 Since it's expected that all stars possess at least a faint residual rotation (after perhaps being slowed by gravitational interactions with other stars or many smaller astronomical bodies), why do you feel that to be "not really the case of a Kerr BH"?  (A reference would be helpful.)